# Pointers are too costly memory wise?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, memory, simulation

I know this is not appropriate , but I wanted to get SO's opinion .

I am building a simulation where the objects have to interact with each other. So inorder too keep track of the other object an object interacts with , I am keeping pointers to them. But in my case , an object might have to interact with about 15 000 other objects and hence I end up having to keep 15 000 pointers in a vector for each of the objects . I want at least 1 billion , hopefully more of these objects to do a proper simulation of my problem .

I am thinking of storing the objects in a vector and then just using an index to refer to the object. This way I will be able to just need to keep a vector of 15,000 32 bit integers rather than storing 15,000 64 bit pointers.

One disadvantage of this might be that there will be slow down in performance , but I am willing to give up some performance for larger scale ?

15 000 is the maximum , sometimes I just need to point to a 1000 objects.

Are there any better solutions to this problem ? Has anyone else faced similar problems in simulation etc , and what did you do ?

Are there any good books / articles etc on doing large scale simulation in cpp ? I am also worried about how issues like caching , locking and memory alignment is going to hit my performance .

Thank you for the suggestions in the comments. I wanted to give more information about locality within the problem.

An object only interacts with other objects in its vicinity , and this vicinity are different sections . Meaning , there are sections within the larger space. And if an object is within a section , it only has to interact with other objects within that section. There are some object which interact across sections , but I am ignoring them.

This seems to be the only relevant information that I can give you.

Comment: I am working in 64 bit arch .

Comment: 15000 is not a big number, even 15000*64bit = 120kb is nothing I would worry about unless there is a good reason to do so

Comment: Using 32-bit integers instead of 64-bit pointers shrinks your usage by half, but that still leaves you with an enormous number.  32 TB is not better than 64 TB if it still busts your RAM budget.

Comment: @tobi303 it's 15000 per object, and OP has a billion objects.

Comment: @tobi303 1 billion * 15000 * 64bit is large, though.

Comment: "One disadvantage of this might be that there will be slow down in performance..." Have you tested this? It seems counter-intuitive to me: a block of contiguous memory, where objects are laid out one after another, should make it easier on the CPU's data cache, unlike pointer chasing.

Comment: @T.C. ups I missed the 1 billion factor

Comment: Does each object reference an arbitrary number of other objects, or just a tiny subset (like 15k)?

Comment: 1 billion objects * 1000 indices minimum per object * 4 bytes per index = 4 terabytes. I think you need to reconsider your design.

Comment: @Nelxiost actually that makes 120Tb, even for half of that I dont know a machine with enough ram

Comment: @KennyOstrom Just a tiny subset. There is locality within the problem I am hoping to utilize ?

Comment: We need more information about your simulation. There are probably links and patterns you haven't thought of, that can lead to enormous memory saving. @tobi303 Yup, that *is* large.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah , I know , I am looking for a better design . I am thinking about using something like a heirarchy to cut down on the space , but I am not sure how much it might help

Comment: If you have 1 billion objects, it's unlikely they are going to be in memory, regardless of design. So how can you fetch a managable (and useful) chunk and work on a useful subproblem, which advances towards one complete step in the simulation?

Comment: 15000 < 65535, so you might as well keep it in a 16-bit unsigned int. At this point I'd say to have a reference getter (e.g. `T& GetPtrA() { return m_vector[m_a]; }`), so you can keep this as an implementation detail even within the class.

Comment: @nnrales If you only need to interact with points within the nearby area then a quad or oct-tree may be better

Comment: You have a potential memory issue just if you want to have a billion objects in memory at once, without any references among them.  If each one's members consisted of only 3 `float` coordinates, for example, then you're already talking about 12 GB.  Machines do exist that have that much RAM and more, but they're not exactly common, in your problem is surely larger in fact.

Comment: @lorro Indices, in a vector with about a billion elements, cannot be represented as 16-bit integers.

Comment: @Nelxiost @ lorro I am actually designing the system with an idea similar to lorros . I can subdivide the space into sections. 1 million sections. And with in each of these 1 million section , there only has to be about ~ 10,000 - 15,000 objects. So that is one way I hope to tackle this problem. So to index an object , first go to the section , then go to the object within the section.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Thank for those data structures , then seem to be helpful.

Comment: Additionally, instead of referencing other related objects directly from the current object, is there a more efficient way to get that relation implicitly from the way you store the current state of the simulation.  If you have sections, you don't need a list of relations, you just iterate over that section.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yep. I tried a previous simulation on a device with 8 gb and it did not have enough objects in it . I think I will be able to get a machine with 64 gb and I am waiting for it.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Can you give me an example of a data structure when you can implicity get the relation ? I can't quite visualize what you are suggesting.

Comment: well, you already have sections, so you already have done so. Everything in that section is in that section.

Answer (score 3):

> An object only interacts with other objects in its vicinity , and this vicinity are different sections . [...] And if an object is within a section , it only has to interact with other objects within that section.

If every object within a section interacts with every other objects in the same section, you can just keep track of the section your objects live in. Considering you don't have too many sections, you can probably do that with a single `int` per object. When you want to know whether two objects have to be interacting, compare their section number.

Another, hopefully better way to do that might require you to redesign your simulation. If objects only live within sections, then make these sections own your objects. That way, you don't need the extra "section number" for each object. When considering interactions, simply operate within one section at a time.

Also, [as vu1p3n0x said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999707/pointers-are-too-costly-memory-wise?noredirect=1#comment63443928_37999707), you might want to consider using [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (or similar higher dimension trees). It really depends on the kind of simulation you are building.

> There are some object which interact across sections , but I am ignoring them.

There are several ways to represent interactions across sections.

One way is to make them a totally different kind of data. An interaction would be represented by two sections, and within these sections, either the list of objects that are "on the edge" and can interact across the sections, or the list of actual interactions between couples of objects, depending on your simulation.

Another way is, in each section, to store differently objects that can interact across sections, let's call them border objects. Let's say that each section can interact with (objects within it can interact across) four other sections. You then store your objects in five different containers : one where objects cannot interact across sections, let's call them center objects, and one per other section for border objects. These four latter containers represent the borders of the section. When iterating over objects of a section, you first consider the center objects as you would before. Then, for each border, you consider its border objects as well as the border objects from the corresponding section. This assumes that any object in a given section can interact with objects within the same section or within only one other section.

Comment: I don't think you can just ignore other sections, but maybe you can iterate across the current section plus adjacent neighbor sections. If you're ignoring things two sections away, that's different from ignoring things one section away (which may in fact be closer than a lot of objects in the same section).

Comment: @KennyOstrom OP says "but I am ignoring them (interactions across sections)". Nonetheless, I don't think nnrales actually can ignore them, so I tried to answer that problem as well. Your comment gave me an idea though (see my second solution to that problem), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the memory to store, for each object, the list of other objects it interacts with, then an easy way to save memory is to simply *not* store the list and *recompute* it every time you need it.

Or, if needed, store a small amount of information that lets you regenerate the list.

This assumes that your problem actually allows that.

---

Similarly, you can save portions of the data to disk and reload it as necessary. This requires knowing how to do I/O efficiently, of course. (unless you're doing a *lot* of computation on each part of the data before moving onto the next part)

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted. Given the problem size, this is the *only reasonable* approach: even using external memory on a cluster, this problem requires > 60 TiB of memory. This isn’t something even bigger institutes/companies can “just” cough up for a computation.

Answer (score 0):

Simulation is just too broad to answer exactly what you are asking.

The best thing I could say is that there is always a:

> trade-off between speed and space.

So, usually more space means more speed (you pay more space to get faster execution, makes sense, doesn't it?).

---

If you use integers of 32 bits, rather than pointers of 64 bits, then you would decrease the space requirements of your project. However, when it comes to speed, you can only know if it is acceptable or the performance drops rapidly.

I would suggest you to test/profile your code, by enabling optimization flags for your compiler (for examle `-03` in [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b)) with both cases and measure the execution time.

If the execution time differs by little with the approach that takes less memory, then I would probably choose than one. But again here, it is worth-noting that:

*you should decide what's critical for your application, speed or space!*

Comment: More space means less speed, typically.

Comment: @SamCristall that's why you downvoted? More space usually means more speed, because you are storing information that can speed-up the process. However, there are situations that you are saying holds true.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but speed vs space is a tricky subject and very application specific.  While you think you might be caching data to reduce the overall work of your program, you could just be increasing cache misses.

Comment: Damn, I wish the downvoter would leave a comment or something @SamCristall! Well, I am not referring to cache. I am referring in situations like computing distances, where you keep track of computed distances that are likely to be needed in the future (thus we require more space, but we are faster).

Answer (score 0):

It think that there is no need to keep a vector of pointers for each object, unless the vector is going to be different for each object. If each object is going to interact with all other objects, you only need to keep one vector of references and just skip the interaction between an object and itself when it occurs.

I would not keep information about each couple objects' interaction in memory, I would try and recompute it on the spot (given the size of the problem, that's the only think you can do, unless you are working with super-computers).
That includes the information about whether the interaction will take place at all.

If the objects have memory about their past relationship... I don't know, that's a harder problem. In that case you may be lucky and the set of "memorable relationships" is small for each object, otherwise... It's harder!

Comment: thanks for the comments. I am looking at different ways to reduce the memory and computing the index real time than storing it seems like a good idea to me . But my interactions are quite random , so I do not know how I will compute the indexes.